# Classical Ghost Imaging not reproduced from the setup

Tags: optics, statistical-mechanics, photons, experimental-physics, imaging

I have been trying to reproduce classical ghost imaging(for reference, see [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09500340500147240)). You can check the setup that I have done[image: [![below][2]][2].]
The light beam from the collimator has beam radius of about 0.8 mm.
\begin{equation}
GI(x,y) = \sum_i^n (I_{img}(x,y) - \langle I_{img}(x,y)\rangle)(I_{Obj} -\langle I_{Obj}\rangle )
\end{equation}
where n is number of ensemble taken after every fixed time, $I_{img}(x,y)$ is the intensity distribution in the image arm detected by CCD and $I_{obj} = \int I_{obj}(x,y)dxdy$ or in other words, power measured after the object. $\langle I_{img}\rangle $ and $\langle I_{obj}\rangle$ are the ensemble average of $I_{img}$ and $I_{obj}$ respectively.
The ground glass is rotated manually and the CCD and power meter takes data every 0.1 second. The exposure time of the CCD was set to 21 ms and $n=5510$. Although I am not able to get the ghost image.

The possible reasons that I can think of for the failure:

1. The CCD could not capture all the speckle patterns generated by the ground glass. (Possible fix use a iris to control the aperture)
2. Due to high exposure time, the CCD took some images which had streaks and not the speckles like the image below(possible fix:-Increase power of the laser beam so that I can decrease the exposure time)[image: like this]
3. The paper cited above mentions the crucial conditions to generate ghost image is spatial incoherence and measurement time must be much less than correlation time. The correlation time of the speckles is given by $\tau_c = w_0/v_{rot}$. Since I was rotating the glass plate by hand, the correlation time of the speckles was non-uniform and very small. (Possible fix :- Use a motorized rotation mount which can rotate it very slowly).

Are there any other possible problems with the setup?

The image generated by my experiment is [image]

Comment: A big difference between your setup and the above mentioned paper is the fact that you do not do any imaging of any plane. You need lenses to properly image the right planes in order to observe an image, just like a normal setup, ie. at your powermeter you need an image of your object, and at your CCD you need also to image a "virtual" plane that would contain the object.

Comment: If  I am not using any imaging system, ideally I should get some image, right? It might be blurry but I should get something.

Comment: Not really. Take a white paper sheet and put it next to a window. look at the image that is projected from the outside on the paper: there is no image, only a bright piece of paper, not even a blurry image. Only when you would use a lens could you form an image of what is outside onto your piece of paper. Same thing here. Please note that a shadow is not the same thing as an image. What you need is to properly image everything.

Comment: To be clear. The window/paper thing is about the light that falls onto the paper and is reflected, not transmitted. In other words, instead of a piece of paper you could take a full 100 page notebook and look at the "image" formed on the paper.

Comment: BTW: I see now that you bountied this question and ask for a reputable source: your paper is a reputable source and your paper clearly show that they are, as the name of ghost imaging implies, imaging.